# 502 BAD GATEWAY nginx/1.10.1

Tags: nginx, joomla, joomla3.0

I searched before for answers but I'm still stucked.

I got this message at the bottom of each page of my site:

> 502 BAD GATEWAY nginx/1.10.1

And I really don't understand or know whats all about. It just starts appearing without any change.

Looking forward for your helpful answers.

Comment: You will need to look into your site's error log and access log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

could you have done some updates more so on your PHP version as I was also receiving the same error after updating PHP version from 7.4 to 8. If that's the case you need to ensure that you're using the latest php-fpm package that corresponds to your PHP version